# Want to do the UI like this please help me how to put colored dots after status in html

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, ui

[image]want to show the image on UI like this

Comment: in lwc this UI is needed

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Please share you current LWC code so we can help you.

Comment: <template if:true={isAuthorised}>
<div class="slds-p-left--small slds-p-around--small">
<table>
 <template for:each= {medicalProviders} for:item ="provider" for:index="index">
<tr key={provider.providerName}>
<td class=" slds-p-left--medium">{provider.providerName}</td>
 <td class=" slds-p-left--medium">{provider.status}</td>
</tr>
</template>
</table>
</div>
</template>
<template if:false={isAuthorised}>
<div class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-size--1-of-1">
<img src={MRRImage}><br/>
You have not yet authorized
</div>
</template></div>

Comment: If the value in Status value is 'Active' than i have to show green dot and if the Status value is 'In-Progress' than have to show yellow dot so wanted to know how will i achieve this ask

Comment: Could you add those comments to the question? You should be able to edit/update it. Also, see [ask] to find some guidance on how to ask good questions that are likely to receive high-quality answers.

Answer (score 1):

In LWC, you can use the utility:record icon and change it's color using a style sheet.

In the.css file you would define the color as shown below:

```
.green-dot {
--sds-c-icon-color-foreground-default: green;
}
.red-dot {
--sds-c-icon-color-foreground-default: red;
}
```

In your html do the following:

```
<lightning-icon icon-name="utility:record" class="green-dot">
 </lightning-icon>

 <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:record" class="red-dot">
 </lightning-icon>
```